# p:watermark doesn't display in firefox when using styleClass or style

Tags: jsf, firefox, primefaces, liferay

xhtml

```
<div class="ui-fluid">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-4" layout="grid"
                 styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank" style="margin-top: 10px;">

        <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{Admin.firstName}"
            required="true"
                     styleClass="addStudent"
            label="firstName"
            validatorMessage="Please specify the student's firstname">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:watermark for="firstName" value="First Name" />

        <p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{Admin.lastName}"
            required="true" styleClass="addStudent"
            label="lastName"
            validatorMessage="Please specify the student's lastname">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:watermark for="lastName" value="Last Name (will also be username)" />

        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{Admin.email}"
            required="true" styleClass="addStudent"
            lable="email"
            validatorMessage="Please specify the student's email">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:watermark for="email" value="email" />


        <p:commandButton value="Add" icon="fa fa-user-plus" action="#{Admin.addStudent}"
                        styleClass="addButton" ajax="false" style="padding: 4px; margin-top: 15px;"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</div>
```

css

```
.addStudent {
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA !important;
    background: #EAEAEA !important;
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
    color: #444 !important;
    padding: 18px 0px 18px 10px !important;
    border-radius: 6px !important;
}
```

The watermarks won't show in firefox, instead an empty inputText is shown.
Only if the `styleClass` is removed then the watermark is shown.

I also tried `style="padding: 18px 0px 18px 10px;"` instead of `styleClass` but still nothing.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. What JSF version etc are you exactly using?

Comment: I am using jsf 2.1. I think it has something to do with padding and placeholder in firefox, not a jsf issue.

Comment: I also can not reproduce your issue with the CSS provided.  What version of PrimeFaces?

Comment: I am using primefaces 5.3, I am also using `ui-fluid` and `panelGrid` which is making the textbox really small for some reason.

Comment: So it works in chrome? And it also works in FireFox if you don't use liferay?